# Assign value while assigning values

Tags: javascript, object

Im starting to work more and more with Javascript and I occasinally run into the following problem.
I want to assign values, based on *values I just entered*.

**Simple example:**

```
var Example = {
    valueA : 100,
    valueB : 20,
    valueC : Example.valueA / Example.valueB
}
```

But this gives `Example is undefined` at the `valueC` line. I'm assuming that the `Example` object isn't ready to be used at this point, it first has to "finish being made".

**I could do:**

```
var Example = {
    valueA : 100,
    valueB : 20,
    valueC : -1 // Gets value later
}
Example.valueC = Example.valueA / Example.valueB
```

In this example this would be perfectly accaptable, but I end up in situations where I would have a lot of these "*post init*" problems, or the assigned values are a bit more complecated (eg a formulae).

**Can something like "Simple Example" work?** My Current solution feels like overkill, I need something more elegant which reads better when reading the code.

Comment: Ah, so that's what it's called. Didnt have a clue, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

> The `get` syntax binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up.

An advantage is, you can assign other values to property `valueA` or `valueB` and get the actual result of the division.

```js
var Example = {
    valueA: 100,
    valueB: 20,
    get valueC() { 
        return this.valueA / this.valueB;
    }
};

document.write(Example.valueC);
```

Comment: But this would make `valueC` a function? This will be a variable I'll call often, wouldn't that be a bit intens?

Comment: yes, it's a function, but it the call works without parenthesis and it acts like a variable with a value. don't worry about the calling.